# jsf f:ajax tag corrupts request

Tags: ajax, spring, jsf, jsf-2

Am using Spring with JSF

I have a view scoped bean which contains a function, the xhtml file contains a dropdown menu which on value change updates some message to the user and a button which calls the function. When I change the dropdown and click the button, the function is not called

Upon removing the tag 
`<f:ajax event="blur" render="type_message" />`, the function is called and it worked fine

it same problem as in [Primefaces Commandbutton not working after an update made by select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21717758/primefaces-commandbutton-not-working-after-an-update-made-by-select-box)

```
@Scope("view")
@Component("propertyBean")
public class PropertyBean implements Serializable {
    ...
    public String update() {
    ...
       return"/page.xhtml";
    }
}
```

xhtml

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="type" required="true"
    requiredMessage="#{msgBean.getRequired()}"
    styleClass="btn btn-white dropdown-toggle" style="width:100%"
    value="#{propertyBean.property.propertyDetails.type}"
    converter="#{typeConverter}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="choose item"
    noSelectionOption="true" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{dataBean.availableTypes}"
    var="typeObj" itemValue="#{typeObj}"
    itemLabel="#{typeObj.type}"/>
    <f:ajax event="blur" render="type_message" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:message id="type_message" for="type"
    infoClass="help-block" errorClass="help-block error" />


    <h:commandButton id="update" value="save"
    onclick="if( validate('submitForm')==true){ updateProperty();} else{ return false;}"
    action="#{propertyBean.update}"
    class="btn btn-green btn-lg arabic"
    rendered="#{propertyBean.isNew == false}">
    <f:param name="propertyId" value="#{propertyBean.property.id}">
    </f:param>
</h:commandButton>
```

on changing `<f:ajax>` to `<p:ajax>` it worked, any explanations

Comment: You are likely trying to write to the response buffer after the response has been sent to the client, perhaps, after this line, `context.getExternalContext().redirect("/page.xhtml");` or the request has already been forwarded / dispatched before this line.

Comment: yes, it appears that ajax wrote the response when I change the dropdown